# Error: Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, perceptron

I know I am facing a very common error, but in this case I am very confused and I don't know the reason why I am getting this error, because the error occured into a function of which the code is already written from a university and many others have used this code beforehand, I guess.

So, my code is about multiclass classification on fisher iris data set using perceptron(single layer, so for 3 classes of the data set I need 3 separate classifiers through one-vs-all method).

The code I took into account is the [perceptron function from Toronto university](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/csc321/tutorialcode/perceptron.m).

**perceptron function (perceptron.m)** (a little bit modified by me):

```
function [w_per] = perceptron(X,Y,w_init)

w_per = w_init;
for iteration = 1 : 100 
    for ii = 1 : size(X,2) % Cycle through training set
        if sign(w_per'*X(:,ii)) ~= Y(ii) % Wrong decision?
            w_per = w_per + X(:,ii) * Y(ii);   % then add (or subtract) this point to w_per
        end
     end
     % Show misclassification rate
     misclassification_rate = sum(sign(w_per'*X)~=Y)/size(X,2); // HERE IS THE POINT I AM GETTING THE ERROR
     disp(misclassification_rate);
end
```

I have also inserted my code below (regarding only the first case, that is the case the class "Setosa" of the data set is the first class and the other two classes "Versicolor" and "Virginica" are the second class of my perceptron):

```
% Perceptron

t1 = randperm(50);
X1a = meas(t1(1:35),3:4);
t2 = randperm(100);
X2a = meas(50 + t2(1:35),3:4);
clear t1 t2;
Xa = [X1a X2a];
Ya = [-ones(1,35) ones(1,35)];
wa = rand(35,1);
wtaga = perceptron(Xa,Ya,wa); % call perceptron
ytaga = wtaga'*Xa; % predict

figure;
hold on;
plot(X1a(1,:),X1a(2,:),'b.');
plot(X2a(1,:),X2a(2,:),'r.');

plot(Xa(1,ytaga<0),Xa(2,ytaga<0),'bo');
plot(Xa(1,ytaga>0),Xa(2,ytaga>0),'ro');

legend('class +1','class -1','pred +1','pred -1');
title('Setosa');
```

Despite I have commented the line where the error occurs in perceptron.m function I write the error message once again:

```
Matrix dimensions must agree

Error in perceptron (line 13)
     misclassification_rate = sum(sign(w_per'*X)~=Y)/size(X,2);
```

Could anyone help me? I would appreciate it!

Comment: Try to troubleshoot. Before the line that gives you error put the following: `size(w_per),size(X),size(Y)` and run the program again. Post results here, so we can help you

Comment: I put them but still same error..Moreover, I assigned sizes to s1,s1,s3 variables respectively to be able to find them in workspace, but they were never created. When even I tried to find size(w_per), size(X) and size(Y) through the command window what I got was an "undefined function or variable 'w_per' or 'x' etc..

Comment: Because I had some suspicions about the size of these matrices as well, I checked the size(wa),size(Xa) and size(Ya) where w_per, X, Y take their initial values into the function respectively.  So, size(wa) = 35x1 , size(Xa) = 35x4 and size(Ya) = 1x70.

Comment: I had also some suspicions that something may be wrong with the Y matrix on the line where the error occurs..check it out please!

Comment: multiplying 1x35 row vector (`w_per`) by 35x4 column vector (`X`) you would get 1x4 vector (`w_per'*X`). `sign(w_per'*X)` would also have dimension 1x4. So, you cannot compare 1x4 vector `sign(w_per'*X)` with 1x70 vector `Y`. Therefore, you have the dimension mismatch. In other words, `sign(w_per'*X)~=Y` is invalid because the expression on the left from `~=` sign has not the same dimensions as the expression on the right size.

Comment: Right..but Ya must have exactly 2 columns, mustn't it? Thinking of being -1 or 1. Or am I wrong? If not, I have to adjust my X1a and X2a to have one and only column each one so that the Xa vector have 2 columns in total(same number of columns-and rows, of course- with Ya vector). What I am thinking however is that, if so, I will have to take into consideration only one attribute(while I need in this case only one column for X1a and X2a), but I want to create a perceptron classifier which takes into account 2 of 4 attributes of fisher iris data set..Pff what is the right thing I should do?

Comment: The solution for your problem highly depends on what you might want to do. To answer it, one would need to dig deeply into your code and maybe some external information. So, I suggest you to think about this error by your own or with your advisor and to come up with more specific question.

Comment: I solved it!! The key(first step to solution) was that I had to write Ya = [-ones(35,1) ones(35,1)]; instead of Ya = [-ones(1,35) ones(1,35)];